# change background colour between animated activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, background

I'm relative new on Android and my English is far to be good.. but everything have it first time.

I have a trouble with the background between two animated activities with translation. I tried to change it via a new theme parent from theme.light.

this is the code:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#d1e3e3</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item> 
</style>
```

But with this I'm in the same. The background between activities still being black.

Thanks for any help or indication!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the same custom color to windowBackground and colorBackground, for that is always the same color and this not change.

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#d1e3e3</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item> --look
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item> --look
</style>
```

i hope that's  help, becouse i can't test now.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering Freak. The problem was it have to change from black (what i see) to #d1e3e3 but it never chenged. Finally today I had done by other way. The activity that gets out still being there for a while with startOffSet. Then i removed all visibe items and then I have the same result.

¬¬

Comment: Yes the best way now that i checking is using the starOffSet, if you need help check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).